# joining column name with actual data

Tags: sql, oracle

I have to populate the data into `FCT_M_INDEX` , by joining  `STG_M_INDEX` and `LKP_M_INDEX`.
table structure are as `follows.LKP_M_INDEX` has index no for each column name in STG_M_INDEX . which I need to populate in FACT. Please advice.

```
 STG_M_INDEX            

**Day_Key     Dow_jones_Price   Dow_jones_Vol   Nasdaq_Closing_Price**
20130920       5312.37            5074030000              3796.28


LKP_M_INDEX         

**Index_no    Index_Name     Index_Data_value     STG_LKP_NAME**
1      Dow Jones     Price                          Dow_jones_Price
2      Dow Jones     Vol                            Dow_jones_Vol
3      Nasdaq        Price                          Nasdaq_Closing_Price
4      Nasdaq        Vol                            Nasdaq_Vol


FCT_M_INDEX         

**Day_Key   Index_Name  INDEX_SCENARIO             VALUE**
20130920     1            Dow_jones_Price          5312.37
20130920     2            Dow_jones_Vol            5074030000
20130920     3            Nasdaq_Closing_Price     3796.28
20130920     4            Nasdaq_Vol               2711270000
```

Thanks, 
Narendra

Comment: I may have misread your question. Is it not about `INSERTing` data, but about how to do your `JOIN`?

Comment: do anybody have any soluion for above issue?

Comment: I revised my answer yesterday. What continues to be the issue?

Comment: You need to unpivot your `STG_M_INDEX`, join the unpivoted set to `LKP_M_INDEX`, then pull the relevant columns from the joined set to insert them into `FCT_M_INDEX`. Look into the `UNPIVOT` clause in the manuals, in case your version of Oracle supports it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to insert data into a table from different tables you.

```
INSERT INTO InsertIntoTableName ( Column1, ... ColumnN) 
    SELECT Column1, ... ColumnN
    FROM DataFromTableName
        -- JOINS if required...
    --WHERE if required
```

For your situation:

```
SELECT Day_Key, Index_no, STG_LKP_NAME, Nasdaq_Closing_Price
FROM STG_M_INDEX, LKP_M_INDEX
```

This performs what is called a `CROSS JOIN` use this with care as it can cause extremely large result sets.

Comment: I want the output as given in FCT_M_INDEX  by selecting ang joining data from STG_M_INDEX  and LKP_M_INDEX   .

Comment: problem is column names from STG_M_INDEX  tables has index no given in LKP_M_INDEX . so I will have to join actual column names from  STG_M_INDEX   with data from     LKP_M_INDEX . this I am not sure how to do.

Comment: So how do you want your data to end up? Every row in `STG_M_INDEX` to have 4 entries (current count of `LKP_M_INDEX`)?

Comment: yes I think I have missed 4th column Nasdaq_Vol
 from STG_M_INDEX            

**Day_Key     Dow_jones_Price   Dow_jones_Vol   Nasdaq_Closing_Price Nasdaq_Vol**
20130920       5312.37            5074030000              3796.28 2711270000